# How to set default value 0 and how to remove the error "null value in column"?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-studio

```
    public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDB.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "expenses";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
    public static final String COLUMN_AMOUNT = "amount";
    public static final String COLUMN_DESC = "description";
    public static final String COLUMN_INC = "income";
    private HashMap hp;
    public int inc;

    public Database(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME , null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL(

                "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ("
                        + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                        + COLUMN_AMOUNT + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0, "
                        + COLUMN_DESC + " TEXT NULL, "
                        + COLUMN_INC + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0)");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS expenses");
        onCreate(db);
    }

    private Integer doUpdateInc() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor rss =  db.rawQuery( "select income from expenses ", null );
        rss.moveToFirst();
        String inc = rss.getString(rss.getColumnIndex(Database.COLUMN_INC));
        return Integer.parseInt(inc);
    }


    public boolean insertExpense  (Integer id,Integer amount, String description)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put("amount", amount);
        contentValues.put("description", description);
        Integer inc = doUpdateInc();
        db.insert("expenses", null, contentValues);

        ContentValues conttValues = new ContentValues();
        conttValues.put("income", inc - amount);
        db.update("expenses", conttValues, "id = ? ", new String[] { Integer.toString(id) } );
        return true;
    }
```

I am getting this error

```
Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
                                                                             at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:426)
                                                                             at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
                                                                             at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
                                                                             at com.sohaib.dailyexpense.Database.doUpdateInc(Database.java:77)
                                                                             at com.sohaib.dailyexpense.Database.insertContact(Database.java:87)
```

What I want to do is: I call the function " insertExpense" on button,
and I want to add two values in amount and description.. and in that function I want to fetch income value and do minus from amount and update in income column again. If I have 0 values in app database than app crashes, and if I add value by changing some code and than I run my app than it runs smoothly.

Comment: You have missing Semicolon on this line `+ COLUMN_INC + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0);`

Comment: done. still not working.

Comment: Same error ya error is change ? 
Other wise uninstall your old app's from your device & try again

Comment: same error. i think error can b solved if default value can b set by 0

Comment: how to create table on the beginning of app run. i debug now. insertExpense method called first before the database

Comment: Try with Text Value its getting to error or no like `TEXT DEFAULT 'TTEESSTT');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 private Integer doUpdateInc() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor rss =  db.rawQuery( "select income from expenses ", null );
        rss.moveToFirst();
        if (rss.getCount() > 0){
            String inc = rss.getString(rss.getColumnIndex(Database.COLUMN_INC));
            return Integer.parseInt(inc);
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Solved by applying this code.

Answer (score 1):

At first your `Cursor` does not have any rows. Check the boolean return value of `moveTo...()` before attempting to call any of the `get...()` methods. It will return `true` only if the cursor is pointing to a valid row.

The `DEFAULT` values in your `CREATE TABLE` affect column values, not rows. The default will be used when you insert a row that does not have a value for that column.